# error during sbt launcher: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/Trees

Tags: scala, sbt

When I try to run sbt in my project folder I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/Trees
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at xsbt.boot.Pre$.classMissing$1(Pre.scala:74)
        at xsbt.boot.Pre$.$anonfun$getMissing$1(Pre.scala:76)
        at xsbt.boot.Pre$.$anonfun$getMissing$1$adapted(Pre.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.filter(List.scala:529)
        at xsbt.boot.Pre$.getMissing(Pre.scala:76)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.checkLoader(Launch.scala:278)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.provider$1(Launch.scala:414)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.$anonfun$getScalaProvider0$2(Launch.scala:417)
        at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:283)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getScalaProvider0(Launch.scala:416)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:400)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:399)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:55)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:47)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:36)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:392)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScalaProvider(Launch.scala:399)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.$anonfun$scalaProviders$1(Launch.scala:228)
        at xsbt.boot.Cache.newEntry(Cache.scala:17)
        at xsbt.boot.Cache.getFromReference(Cache.scala:13)
        at xsbt.boot.Cache.apply(Cache.scala:11)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScala(Launch.scala:212)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScala(Launch.scala:210)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:368)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$1.call(Launch.scala:304)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$1.call(Launch.scala:303)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:113)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:91)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.$anonfun$withFileLock$1(Locks.scala:119)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:12)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withFileLock(Locks.scala:119)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:71)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:59)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:47)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:36)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:392)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.getAppProvider(Launch.scala:303)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:215)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:213)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:140)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$apply$1(Launch.scala:44)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:159)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:44)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:21)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.run(Boot.scala:73)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at coursier.bootstrap.launcher.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at coursier.bootstrap.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.reflect.internal.Trees
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 79 more
[error] [launcher] error during sbt launcher: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/Trees
```

What cause this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Try `sbt clean` and then `run`.

Comment: Got the same result

Comment: I don't know what caused the problem. I just reinstalled JDK and sbt and it started working.